# Cómo puedo "convertir" este código de Angular ya obsoleto en esta sintaxis que me genera el comando ng g guard?

Tags: javascript, angular, framework, auth, guards

En un curso de Angular que estoy haciendo lo hacen así, pero creo que esa versión es del 2020 aprox y me lo toma como deprecated.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la forma en la que Angular 17 me lo genera, haciendo uso de ng g guard y seleccionando canMatch, que vendría siendo el equivalente a canLoad de la imagen anterior.

```
import { CanMatchFn } from '@angular/router';

export const authGuard: CanMatchFn = (route, segments) => {
  return true;
};
```

Información extra: Lo uso para permitir cargar la página si y solo si se encuentra un id proveniente del servicio AuthService en esa página.

```
{
    path: 'heroes',
    loadChildren: () => import('./heroes/heroes.module').then(m => m.HeroesModule),
    canMatch: [authGuard]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Se usa la función `inject` para obtener una instancia del servicio que se desea utilizar.

```
export const authGuard: CanMatchFn = (route, segments) => {
  const authService = inject(AuthService);
  // resto del código
};
```

Comment: Es que me sale este error:

core.mjs:7473 ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:4674:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:5117:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:5117:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:3831:40)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:3837:42)
    at Object.AuthService_Factory [as factory] (auth.service.ts:8:25)
    at core.mjs:5239:43
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:3644:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:5238:17)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:5106:33)

Comment: Es raro porque el provider lo tengo en app.component y el httpClientModule lo tengo importado en mi modulo